# Prove that the maximum of $n$ independent standard normal random variables, is asymptotically equivalent to $\sqrt{2\log n}$ almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Lets $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an iid sequence of standard normal random variables. Define $$M_n=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} X_i.$$
Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}=1\quad\text{a.s.}$$

I used the fact that $$\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\leq\mathbb P(X_n>x)\leq \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},$$

and the Borel Cantelli lemmas to prove that 
 $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{X_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}=1\quad\text{a.s.}$$

I used Davide Giraudo's comment to show $$\limsup_n \frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}=1\quad \text{a.s.}$$

I have no idea how to compute the $\liminf$. Borel-Cantelli give us tools to compute the $\limsup$ of sets, I am unsure of how to argue almost sure convergence. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Your estimate gives that for each positive $\varepsilon$, we have
$$\sum_i\mathbb P(M_{2^{i}}>(1+\varepsilon)\sqrt 2\sqrt{i+1})<\infty$$
(we use the fact that $\mathbb P(M_n>x)\leqslant n\mathbb P(X_1\gt x)$).

We thus deduce that $\limsup_iM_{2^{i}}/(\sqrt{2(i+1)})\leqslant 1+\varepsilon$ almost surely. Taking $\varepsilon:=1/k$, we get $\limsup_iM_{2^{i}}/(\sqrt{2(i+1)})\leqslant 1$ almost surely. To conclude, notice that if $2^i\leqslant n\lt 2^{i+1}$,
$$\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\leqslant \frac{M_{2^{i+1}}}{\sqrt{2i}}.$$

For the $\liminf$, define for a fixed  $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$, $$A_n:=\left\{\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\lt 1-\varepsilon\right\}.$$
By independence, $\mathbb P(A_n)=\left(\mathbb P\left(X_1<(1-\varepsilon)\sqrt{2\log n}\right)\right)^n$ and using inequalities on the tail of a standard normal distribution shows that the series $\sum_n \mathbb P(A_n)$ is convergent. Therefore, the Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that $\mathbb P\left(\limsup_n A_n\right)=0$. This means that for almost every $\omega$, we can find $N=N(\omega)$ such that if $n\geqslant N(\omega)$, then $$\frac{M_n(\omega)}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\geqslant 1-\varepsilon.$$
This implies that $$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{M_n(\omega)}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\geqslant 1-\varepsilon \quad \mbox{a.e.}$$
Here again, taking $\varepsilon:=1/k$, we obtain that
$$\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac{M_n(\omega)}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\geqslant 1\quad \mbox{a.e.}$$

Comment: So I am mainly having trouble with justifying the first sum converges. I get $$\mathbb{P}(M_{2^i}>\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)2(i+1)})=1-(1-\mathbb{P}(X_{2^i}>\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)2(i+1)}))^{2^i} 

\leq 1-(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)2(i+1)}}e^{-(1+\epsilon)(i+1)})^{2^i}$$

Comment: yes significantly. Thank you. So that shows that $\limsup$ of $\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\leq 1$, but not the $\liminf\geq1$.

Comment: It may be not the case that $\liminf\geq 1$, however the limsup is greater than $1$ because $M_n\geq X_n$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that you have a limit and not only a limsup.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to tackle the liminf?

Comment: See edit. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry for responding to an early question but can you explain how you got $\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{2\log n}}\leqslant \frac{M_{2^{i+1}}}{\sqrt{2i}}$. This would seem to require that $\log n\geq i$ but I can only deduce that $\log n \geq i\log 2$. Also could you give more of a hint on how to deduce that $\sum P(A_n)<\infty$. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @FoobazJohn I agree with your objection. I would not only work with $M_{2^i}$, but also with $M_{\lfloof 1+a\rfloor^i}$ where $a\gt 0$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you for the answer and upvoted! (not my question). I'm interested to know to what extent, i.e. to what class of random variables we can generalize this a.s. limit to, e.g. perhaps to normalized sequence of random variables $X_n$ that satisfies: $ 
 EX_n = 0, EX_n^2=1,\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\leq\mathbb P(X_n>x)\leq \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}?$ Or if we can't have a limit, can we at least show that both the lim sup and lim inf are close to $\sqrt{2 log n}?$

Comment: Why $\sum\Bbb P(A_n)$ converges?

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato I have added a bit more details.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a related comment that is too long for a comment box ...

This question made me curious to compare:

- the pdf of the sample maximum (given a sample of size $n$ drawn on a N(0,1) parent), say $f(x;n):$

$$f(x) = \frac{2^{\frac{1}{2}-n} n e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \left(1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$
where erf(.) denotes the error function, to

- the asymptote proposed by the question $\sqrt{2 \log n}$

... when $n$ is very large (say $n$ = 1 million).

The diagram compares:

[image]

The distribution does not, in fact, converge to the asymptote in any meaningful manner, even when $n$ is very large, such as $n$ = 1 million or 100 million or even a billion.

Comment: Are you using the right logarithm? (I.e. base $e$ and not base 10?)

Comment: Yes - $\sqrt{2 \log \left(10^6\right)}$ = 5.25 ... as shown in the diagram above (the red line). By contrast, with base 10, the same calculation would be equal to $2 \sqrt{3}$ which is approx 3.46.

Comment: Using the large-$x$ asymptotics of the error function, I found that the maximum is attended at $\sqrt {2\log n} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right)} \right)$, showing that the convergence is very slow.