# Approximate normal distribution

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Let $ X \sim N (0, 1)$. For $x$ large enough, the tail of the distribution of $X$ may be approximated as $$P(X > x) \sim e^{-x^2/2}/(x\sqrt{2\pi})$$
Consider a sequence of independent r.v. all having a standard normal distribution. For every $a > 0$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots$, define the event $$U_{a,n} =\left \lbrace X_n \ge a\times \log(n)\right \rbrace.$$

**a)** Calculate $P(\limsup \, U_{a,n})$, which may depend on $a$.
**b)** Prove $\limsup \left(X_n/\sqrt{\log(n)} \right) = \sqrt{2} $ a.e.

Should we do this question by thinking about the distribution of $X/\sqrt{\log(n)}$? Or just plug in $ \{X_n \ge a\times \log(n)\}$ into the formula above?

I did it but cannot proceed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for a fixed $a$, the events $(U_{a,n})_{n\geqslant 1}$ are independent. The equivalent given in the opening post allows us to determine the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P(U_{a,n})$. Then we use the $\fbox{B___-__}$ lemma.

For part b), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961780/prove-that-the-maximum-of-n-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-is-a/962029#962029https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961780/prove-that-the-maximum-of-n-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-is-a/962029#962029).

Comment: what about the part b)?

Comment: Does't the answer to part a) help?

Comment: I try to use a) but there is a sqrt in b) and I dont know where the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from. can u give me more hint? thanks a lot

Comment: I included a link.

Comment: the link said he use  the fact that $$\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\leq\mathbb P(X_n>x)\leq \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},$$
and the Borel Cantelli lemmas to prove what I want.but I still cannot see how it is done, can you give me more details? thanks

Comment: If there is something _specific_ which is not clear to you (either in this post or in the linked one), please tell me.