# If $X_k$ are iid standard normal variables, there exists a constant $C$ such that for sufficiently large k $|X_k|\le C\sqrt{\log k}$

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, normal-distribution

> Question: Show that if $X_k$, $k\in\Bbb N$ are iid standard normal variables, then there exists a constant $C$ such that for sufficiently large $k\ge2$ we have $|X_k|\le C\sqrt{\log k}$ almost surely.

To me this isn't even true at first glance because the law of $X_k$ doesn't depend on $k$ and for any $r\in\Bbb R$ (taking $r$ as an arbitrary bound, in particular it can be equal to $C\sqrt{\log k}$) $\Bbb P(|X|> r)>0$ so $\Bbb P(|X|\le r)<1$ not matter how big we choose $C$ or $k$.

Am I wrong or is the question wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the random variables are identically distributed, we have by Markov's inequality

\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq 6 \sqrt{\log n})=\mathbb{P}(|X_1| \geq 6 \sqrt{\log n})  &= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{X_1^2}{4} \geq 9 \log n \right) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(e^{X_1^2/4} \geq e^{9 \log n}) \\ &\leq  \frac{1}{e^{\log n^9}} \mathbb{E}\exp(X_1^2/4) \\ &= \frac{1}{n^9} \underbrace{\mathbb{E}\exp(X_1^2/4)}_{<\infty}.\end{align*}

(Note that $\mathbb{E}\exp(X_1^2/4)$ is finite because $X_1$ is standard Gaussian.) In particular,

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq 6 \sqrt{\log n}) < \infty.$$

By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, this implies that $|X_n| \leq 6 \sqrt{\log n}$ with probability $1$ for $n=n(\omega)$ sufficiently large.

**Remark:** With some more effort, one can show a [stronger result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961780/prove-that-the-maximum-of-n-independent-standard-normal-random-variables-is-a?rq=1).

Comment: I think for the OP, one of the main points of your answer is that $n = n(\omega)$ needs to be sufficiently large. If one wants to choose $n$ independently of $\omega$ (i.e., deterministically), then this is impossible precisely by the argument that the OP gives.

Comment: True. So at what point do we use the fact that $n$ is a random variable?

Comment: Also, why factor 36 as $4\cdot9$ instead of using $36$ the whole time? It should still work (with coefficients ${1\over n^{36}}$ in the sum)

Comment: @H.Walter 1) By the Borel Cantelli lemma, there exists for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|X_n(\omega)| \leq 6 \sqrt{\log n}$ for all $n \geq N$. The number $N$ depends on $\omega$, i.e. we cannot choose it uniformly for all $\omega \in \Omega$. 2) Since you were just asking for some constant (not necessarily the optimal one) I simply picked one which I liked. You can do the same calculation for other constants, i.e. start with $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>C \sqrt{\log n})$. Note that one would like to choose $C$ as small as possible (because this gives a

Comment: stronger bound on the growth of $X_n$). As you can see from the question, which I linked, the optimal constant is $C=\sqrt{2}$.